# How to optimize android apps for multiple cores

Tags: android, multithreading, optimization

With the availability of android phones with multiple cores, how can application developers make sure that their application makes use of the additional processing power of those cores. 
From what I understand, the only thing that app developers can do is make their application multi-threaded and let android kernel take care of delegating the tasks on different cores.

I would like to know if there is anything else that can be done to optimize for multiple cores.Also, what are the best multi-threading practices in android.

Comment: My best-advice with multithreading: *don't* .. *except* where parallelization fits the problem well *and* there is a measurable benefit. It is hard to get correct, and many things (such as the UI) can intrinsically *not* be threaded safely. (For UI tasks that require background processing it's usually simpler to use "background workers", including [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), instead of threads directly.)

Comment: I respectfully disagree, considering that the Android API has come a long way to help alleviate the `Context` tracking-leaking hell, that `synchronized` is our friend, and, finally, that the paradigm is here to stay. Even simple apps have (generally) separate things to initialize/load/... before displaying information, so we should do what we can to end this "multicore is useless" (user) or "multicore is hard" (devs). And it also has the benefit of changing the mentality of most devs about caring for UI thread segregation (#1 cause of slow apps). Point is there are a lot of benefits.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to perform threading yourself its best to use built in paradigms such as AsyncTask.

If you want

```
//Sets up a thread pool where NUM_THREADS is the amount that can run at the same time
ExecutorService threadPool = null;
threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);

//Will execute something on one of the threads queuing if necessary
threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

                      }});
```

Typically web calls and data parsing should be done on a separate thread